# VS 2017 - DotNetAnalyzers Warnings Showing Up in Build Output, But Not Code Analysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm seeing the following in VS 2017 Enterprise on a csproj, Project1, that's being built on .Net 4.5.2:

```
18>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
18>C:\git\27844-2-StyleCop\company\Class1.cs(26,31,26,47): warning CS0169: The field 'Class1.field' is never used
18>C:\git\27844-2-StyleCop\company\Class2.cs(31,48,31,69): warning SA1214: Readonly fields must appear before non-readonly fields
18>C:\git\27844-2-StyleCop\company\Interface1.cs(9,45,9,69): warning SA1127: Generic type constraints must be on their own line
18>  Project1 -> C:\git\27844-2-StyleCop\company\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\Project1.dll
18>  Running Code Analysis...
18>  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Clearly there's 3 warnings there being picked up by a combination of the built-in C# DotNetAnalyzers and version 1.0.2 of the StyleCop.Analyzers. What I'm wondering is why the:

```
18> Code Analysis Complete - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

section is not:

```
18> Code Analysis Complete - 0 error(s), 3 warning(s)
```

and why none of these warnings (or errors for that matter, as I've seen this happen with rules treated as errors) are appearing in the code analysis log file, `Project1.dll.CodeAnalysisLog.xml`

I've tried:

- Turning off/on `Enable Code Analysis on Build` in the project properties
- Turning off/on `Treat Warnings as Errors` in the project properties
- Ensuring there's no `Suppress warnings` in the project properties
- Ensuring that the ruleset I'm using is running on the Configuration / Platform I'm build on
- Cleaning / Rebuilding
- Running Code Analysis explicitly on the project

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build and Code Analysis are separate steps.

StyleCop Analyzers do not run in the Code Analysis step (as per https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/2456 ).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although I'd hoped I would be able to see this through build output, it makes more sense why I can't now. Thanks!